# JButtons hidden by paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have two screens that both extend `GameScreen`, which in turn extends a `JPanel`. My `NavigationFrame` class executes properly, but my `InternalSensorsFrame` is drawing the gray background rectangle over my buttons so that the buttons are hidden and only briefly flicker to visible when you mouse over them. Here is my code. Can anyone tell me why the one example is working and the other is not, and how I can fix it?

```
public class NavigationFrame extends GameScreen {

...
    public NavigationFrame() {
        //super(parent);
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        //background
        img = new ImageIcon(Home.resources.getClass().getResource(imageName));
        bg = new BufferedImage(
        img.getIconWidth(),
        img.getIconHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics gg = bg.createGraphics();
        img.paintIcon(null, gg, 0,0);
        gg.dispose();
        RenderingHints rh =
                new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        rh.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    gameFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);

    //Set Viewscreen to blockmapview
    if (viewScreen == null){
        setViewScreen(new ScrollShipScreen(this, 0));
    }
    viewScreen.setBounds(150, 50, 500, 500);
    add(viewScreen);

    //Buttons
    btnMainComputer = new JButton("Main Computer");
    btnMainComputer.setBounds(140, 560, 120, 23);
    btnMainComputer.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnMainComputer);

    btnInternalSensors = new JButton("Internal Sensors");
    btnInternalSensors.setBounds(330, 560, 130, 23);
    btnInternalSensors.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnInternalSensors);

    btnNavigation = new JButton("Navigation");
    btnNavigation.setBounds(550, 560, 110, 23);
    btnNavigation.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnNavigation);


    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //background
        g.setColor(Color.decode("#666665"));
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
        g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, 0,img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight(), this);

        //text setup
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(gameFont);


        //Write the strings
        //left bar
        g.drawString(location, 10,60);
....

    }



    //Button Presses
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {   
        JButton o = (JButton) ae.getSource();
....
        else if(o == btnMainComputer){
            Container parent  = getParent();
            parent.remove(Home.getCurrentScreen());
            Home.setCurrentScreen(new MainComputerFrame());
            parent.add(Home.getCurrentScreen());
            //System.out.println("Main Comp");
        }
        else if(o == btnInternalSensors){
            Container parent  = getParent();
            parent.remove(Home.getCurrentScreen());
            Home.setCurrentScreen(new InternalSensorsFrame());
            parent.add(Home.getCurrentScreen());
            //System.out.println("Sensors");

        }
        else if(o == btnNavigation){
            //Does nothing on a navigation Frame
//          remove(Home.getCurrentScreen());
//          Home.setCurrentScreen(new NavigationFrame());
//          Home.frame.add(Home.getCurrentScreen());
        }

        this.requestFocus();
    }

}
```

and here is the non-working class:

```
public class InternalSensorsFrame extends GameScreen {
private String imageName = "textures/interface/View Screen Frame Overlay.png";



public InternalSensorsFrame(){
    //super(parent);
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

    //background
    img = new ImageIcon(Home.resources.getClass().getResource(imageName));
    bg = new BufferedImage(
    img.getIconWidth(),
    img.getIconHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics gg = bg.createGraphics();
    img.paintIcon(null, gg, 0,0);
    gg.dispose();
    RenderingHints rh =
            new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
           RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    rh.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    //Add buttons
    btnMainComputer = new JButton("Main Computer");
    btnMainComputer.setBounds(140, 560, 120, 23);
    btnMainComputer.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnMainComputer);

    btnInternalSensors = new JButton("Internal Sensors");
    btnInternalSensors.setBounds(330, 560, 130, 23);
    btnInternalSensors.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnInternalSensors);

    btnNavigation = new JButton("Navigation");
    btnNavigation.setBounds(550, 560, 110, 23);
    btnNavigation.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnNavigation);

}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.decode("#666665"));
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, 0,img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight(), this);
    g2d.translate(150, 50);
    Home.ship.shipLayout.paintComponent(g2d);
//        ArrayList<CrewMan> crew = Home.ship.crew;
//        for (int i=0; i<crew.size(); i++){
//          crew.get(i).paint(g2d);
//        }
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("teststring", 10,60);
        //super.paint(g);

        //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
      //  g.dispose();
}

        //Button Presses
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {   

            JButton o = (JButton) ae.getSource();

            if(o == btnMainComputer){
                Container parent  = getParent();
                parent.remove(Home.getCurrentScreen());
                Home.setCurrentScreen(new MainComputerFrame());
                parent.add(Home.getCurrentScreen());
                //System.out.println("Main Comp");
            }
            else if(o == btnInternalSensors){
                Container parent  = getParent();
                parent.remove(Home.getCurrentScreen());
                Home.setCurrentScreen(new InternalSensorsFrame());
                parent.add(Home.getCurrentScreen());
                //System.out.println("Sensors");

            }
            else if(o == btnNavigation){
                Container parent  = getParent();
                parent.remove(Home.getCurrentScreen());
                Home.setCurrentScreen(new NavigationFrame());
                parent.add(Home.getCurrentScreen());
            }

            this.requestFocus();
        }
}
```

Comment: `super.paintComponent()`.

Comment: Call `super.paintComponent(g)` also don't use `requestFocus` in a `JPanel` and try to not call Frame something that is a `JPanel` cause it's confusing. As a design view, don't use too much inheritance you can do the same with composition and only subclassing using anonymous class.

Comment: Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Don't invoke paintComponent() of another class. Swing will repaint components as needed.

Comment: Nachokk: calling super.paintComponent didn't fix my issue (removing g.dispose() did, see my answer below).
Not calling it a Frame makes a lot of sense. However, it actually does frame an inner JPanel, what would you suggest I call it?
Could you give me more info on using too much inheritance? I'm a noob, and am struggling a bit with my design layout. Thanks man!
Camickr: Yeah, at this point I'm doing a mockup/prototype, but I really need to change that to layout managers...
I'm calling 'Home.ship.shipLayout.paintComponent(g2d);' because otherwise it won't get painted... Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this advices don't solve your issue but may be help.

1)

Call `super.paintComponent(g)` when you override this method.

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //background
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.decode("#666665"));
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
        g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, ...
```

2) `requestFocus()`

> Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its behavior
>   is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of
>   requestFocusInWindow().

3) Use proper name for your classes you are saying that your class is a Frame when in fact is a JPanel.

4) As a personal suggestion don't use too much concrete inheritance cause it's dangereous and hard to mantain, and your inheritance tree level is too high, instead you can use something like this.

Example:

```
public class NavigationComponent {

private GameScreen gameScreen;

public NavigationComponent(){
      gameScreen = new GameScreen(){
           @override
          public paintComponent(Graphics g){
              // code here
          }

      };
}

}
```

5)  You are adding keyListener to a `JPanel`. To get this work you have to make your object focusable and to be in focus.Instead of keyListener the swing way is to use `KeyBinding`. Swing was designed to use with keyBindings.[How to use keybindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem briefly after posting:
Adding `super.paintComponents(g);` did not work/made no difference. In the end it was because I was disposing of the graphics. Here is the working code:

```
    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   // super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.decode("#666665"));
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, 0,img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight(), this);



    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
//  g.dispose(); //commenting this line out made it work
    }
```

However, I much appreciate the answers/comments given here and will work through them to enhance the rest of the code/ will respond in the comments. Thanks!